# How to create database connection for remote database on Altova mapforce

Tags: amazon-web-services, map-force

I am new to mapforce. Is it possible to create database connection for remote DB(on AWS) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AWS server database to generate XML file.
Here is how I did it:
1) Add your DB name and service name into the TNS file.(Found on DB installation folder:C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora)
2) Create a DSN on ODBC data source.
3) Go to mapforce->Insert database
4) Select ODBC connection
5) Select your DSN from the listed DSNs(All your DSNs should appear here).
6) Click on connect.
7) Driver connect window appears,You might need to enter your password.
8) Click on OK
9) You should now see the schema of you database, check on Tables.